# How did the LEGO Duck become a classic icon?

Tags: history, wooden-toys

The [LEGO handmade wooden Duck](http://www.flickr.com/photos/blue-moose/3932223345/in/set-72157622407019674/) was released in 1935, long before the LEGO Brick was created. Many other wooden toys were made which can be seen in [The Lego Museum](http://www.flickr.com/photos/blue-moose/3932222651/in/set-72157622407019674/), the duck however features in books, LEGO's yearly [progress report](http://aboutus.lego.com/en-US/corporate/default.aspx) as well as being [made into a model out of LEGO bricks](https://brickset.com/sets/2011-2/LEGO-Duck)!

I can't find any history of the Ducks being sold on eBay, judging by its age, sentimental value and low production rate it must be a priceless collector's item.

[image]

Comment: It's certainly a very good looking duck.

Comment: Looks like according to [this article](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Duck) it was one of the first toys created by Lego.

Comment: @daviesgeek: Yes, but they made many different wooden toys. Sadly the Wikia article doesn't give more than that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I sent the question to LEGO customer support and they replied:

> The LEGO Duck became a classic icon because it was the first LEGO toy
>   ever to be released.
>
> We do not have any lists of where would sell this product however I
>   imagine it would be sold at some antique markets or antique shows so
>   keep a look out!
>
> We do not have any idea for how much it is worth as it is priceless in
>   our eyes and not sold by LEGO any longer. It also does not have a set
>   number which may be why it is hard to find on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

As said by Ambo100, the duck was the first toy produced by the company.
This animated short story has a [short glimpse of the duck](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdDU_BBJW9Y&t=1m39s) in the design process by Ole Kirk Christiansen.

The film is very interesting as an introduction to the origin of the LEGO company. Click the image below for the full film:

[image: The LEGO Story]